# How to override asp.net GetGlobalResourceObject method?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I would like to know if it is possible to replace `GetGlobalResourceObject()` with my own implementation.

I am looking for a solution that could be easily be applied to a big project that is written in both C# and Visual Basic because I have over 3000 matches in over 300 files.

If I cannot do this at runtime, can I use macros to call my custom function instead of the default one?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. If it had, people would distribute code replacing mscorlib.dll's behavior. I am guessing your best shot is copy/replace.

Comment: follow this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx (Extending the ASP.NET 2.0 Resource-Provider Model)